# how to add method i.e get/post in a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jstl

I am using spring mvc in my project.

```
 <form:form method="" action=""  id="myform" commandName="users">
```

I have this form, want to add action a runtime using jquery. how can I do it
Using javascript I was doing as which worked fine

```
document.getElementById("myform").action = "changePWD"
document.getElementById("myform").method="POST";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#myform').attr('action','changePWD').attr('method','POST');
```

Why would you not do it with Javascript though if that is working fine as you say?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').attr({
    action: 'changePWD',
    method: 'POST'
});
```

But I agree with Kokos, why fix what's not broken?